# Makkot 7a: מעגילה

Tags: words, maseches-makos

The Mishnah mentioned some sort of roller to spread plaster over rooftops. Why is this called  מעגילה especially since it only called that way on the way down?

Answer (score 1):

The same word מעגילה in this folio [appears](http://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.7a.48?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) whether the roller is going up or going down.

Please click on the image to enlarge.

[image: "אלו הן הגולין ההורג נפש בשגגה היה מעגל *במעגילה* ונפלה עליו והרגתו היה משלשל בחבית ונפלה עליו והרגתו היה יורד בסולם ונפל עליו והרגתו הרי זה גולה אבל אם היה מושך *במעגילה* ונפלה עליו והרגתו היה דולה בחבית ונפסק החבל ונפלה עליו והרגתו"]

The gist of the passage is that when going up to the rooftop with the roller, [you were working against gravity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OILof.png). Thus if the roller falls and hurts someone while you were working against gravity, you are not to be exiled from the land.

However, once you are on the rooftop, you now begin to leverage gravity to work for you. Because you are using gravity for your own benefit, you now incur the liability that gravity could pull something out of your control and hurt someone. In such an unfortunate eventuality, you will incur more severe civil liabilities.

Comment: But Rashi there that when one pulls the roller to him he's called מושך and when he pulls away he is called a מעגל. So why is this device called a מעגליה?